# python folium map markers do not show on map despite data

Tags: python, twitter, dictionary, geolocation, maps

i have a code which im following from the book practical data science cookbook in which they used folium and twitter to plot twitter followers geo-location. The code runs well and at the end it outputs a html file which is supposed to have markers of where your followers are. However, my map does not have any markers despite having data.

Here is the code:

```
status_geo = []
status_geo_screen_names = []
for fp in friends_profiles:
    if ('status' in fp and fp['status']['geo'] is not None and 'screen_name' in fp):
        status_geo.append(fp['status']['geo'])
        status_geo_screen_names.append(fp['screen_name'])

print status_geo
```

output:
[{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [37.27647779, -121.98564579]}, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [33.64158125, -84.43924375]}, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [33.81747122, -116.52908589]}, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [34.01340657, -118.17538228]}, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [38.7974924, -76.1285375]}, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [43.579385, -116.198543]}, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [51.69102332, -0.41811924]}, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [40.494286, -74.44376]}, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [53.60089695, -113.49052185]}

```
print status_geo_screen_names
```

Output:
[u'TicaCoffee', u'sekouandrews', u'Kimtuitive', u'isalsa4u', u'ConsWahoo', u'cre8commongood', u'BrookeHRob', u'pedrohernandez', u'khueggen', u'DMCONCREPUMP', u'PhillipLeslie'...]

```
import folium
from itertools import izip

#Let Folium determine the scale
map = folium.Map(location=[38, -120],zoom_start=3)

for sg, sn in izip(status_geo, status_geo_screen_names):
    map.simple_marker(sg['coordinates'], popup=str(sn))

map.create_map(path='us_states.html')
```

We should see something like this:
[image]
but my map does not have any markers no matter where i look or zoom:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that you should NOT be viewing the generated html directly in the browser since it depends on external javascript libs that might not be reference properly in a file:/// path.

Try using a simple python server to serve that file.

First cd into the directory where the generated html file is at.
$ cd /path/to/generated/html/file

$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

Now go to your browser and enter http://localhost:8000/us_states.html (in your case)

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote some code that takes raw twitter data, and creates a CSV file from it with a username, longitude and latitude, which opens nicely in Google earth. Assuming you already have the raw twitter data, you should be able to use this.

```
import sys
import csv
import json

in_file = raw_input("File to read ex: 'C:\\Python27\\twitdata.txt': ")
out_file = raw_input("CSV file/location to write: ")
csvfile = file(out_file, "w")
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
row = [ "user", "latitude", "longitude" ]
csvwriter.writerow(row)
tweets_file = open(in_file, 'r')
for line in tweets_file:
try:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    user = tweet['user']['screen_name']
    latitude = tweet["geo"]["coordinates"][0]
    longitude = tweet["geo"]["coordinates"][1]
    row = [ user, latitude, longitude ]
    csvwriter.writerow(row)
except:
    continue

print "done "
csvfile.close()
```